# How to register an application?

Tags: api, outlook, task

Using the Outlook REST API, I want to make a browser extension (To-Do).  I need graph api and the REST Task API.  I make this application only for myself (maybe I will add it on github).  Tell me, should I register an account as a commercial developer?  Do I need to confirm for this application?  Is it free?  Where can I register the application?  thank

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through the [Quick Start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started) documentation, which will help you pick the appropriate platform and walk you through registering your Graph application. Also join the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program) which will give you a free Office 365 developer subscription that you can use.